# Applying NSDate from server with localtimezone get NSDate

Tags: objective-c, timezone, nsdate

I'm returning an NSDate from my server (running on GMT+2)
I'm calculating few things with the server's date and the device current date.

The problem (obviously) is when the device is running on different timezone then my server.

How can I apply and change the server's NSDate to return current device NSDate for my calculation will be exact for every time zone.

I simply need a function that will get my server NSDate with my server's timezone (gmt+2) and will return the correct device NSDate.

hope someone can help me on that

Server returns Ticks (running on c#) and manipulating to nsdate with this code

```
double tickFactor = 10000000;
double ticksDoubleValue = [ticks doubleValue];
double seconds = ((ticksDoubleValue - 621355968000000000)/ tickFactor);
NSDate *returnDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];
return returnDate;
```

Comment: Best option is to change the server to send the date in UTC.  Barring that, please share the code for creating the NSDate from the server data, including the representation you are receiving from the server.

Comment: Change the server timezone it's kinda impossible I have many things and don't know how it will effect on other application stored.
I'm returning Ticks (my server written c#) and manipulate them to nsdate

Comment: I don't mean change the server's time zone; I mean to change the API to return the date offset from UTC (basically, no offset), instead of a local representation of the time.

Comment: And what code do you use to create the NSDate?

Comment: been added to my question...
got it but still how can UTC will solve my timezone changing problem?

Comment: If you're already adjusting for other reasons, simply adjust for the server's time zone too.  If it's always GMT+2 (no DST to worry about), you can just subtract 7200 (number of seconds per hour * 2) before the `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds]` call.

Comment: UTC is time zone agnostic.  If you have a UTC date, you can apply the local time zone if you want.  The problems start when you get a date that is adjusted to some time zone, because now you have to figure out what that time is locally.  It's even more fun if the time zone can vary.

Comment: thanks for the explanation Avi. if I'll subtract 7200 seconds then still to manipulate things with current system date i will need to adjust it to the current device timezone no?

Comment: You're quite welcome.  Date and time handling can be hard to wrap your head around.  I struggled with it when I wrote my first time-related program.  (Zmanim calculator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSDate` class stores an absolute time.  To facilitate this, it represents time in UTC, which is time-zone-agnostic.  However you create an NSDate, it is assumed the time is in UTC.  Even when you use `NSDateFormatter` to "read" a date from a string, it's just doing the math on your behalf, before creating the `NSDate`.

If you have a time representation that includes a time zone offset, you need to account for that when you do the conversion.  As mentioned above, given a proper format string, `NSDateFormatter` will do that for you.  If your representation is numeric (typically number of seconds from some date), you need to add or subtract the time zone offset.  Add if the offset is negative, subtract if it's positive.

To adjust a server date provided in the server's local time, adjust based on the server's time zone.  For GMT+2, subtract `3600 * 2` (number of seconds per hour * offset).  This gives the seconds in UTC.  When you create the NSDate using `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:]. it will be the expected time.

Comment: I understand what was my problem and fixed it with your help, as you mentioned removed 7200 from seconds
and instead getting the device specific datetime just got NSDate new date wich gives the date with GMT as same as my server date after removing the 3600*2, now everything works perfect! תודה